# twtrdefines.h not found - app doesn't build - Xcode 7, Twitter Fabric SDK

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, xcode7, twitter-fabric

I've been trying to build my project since the last update of twitter's fabric SDK and it just refuses to build. I get three errors which I believe are because of some SDK changes (files removed). Can anyone help me out with this?

These are the errors:

> Header 'TWTRDefines.h' not found ....:1:9: In file
>   included from :1:
>
> Could not build module 'TwitterCore'
>
> Could not build Objective-C module 'TwitterKit'

Actions taken so far:

> Added the file twtrdefines.h from an earlier sdk version manually - didn't work
>
> Commented lines of code causing errors - didn't work

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: bug with sdk. fixed via update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a bug with the Twitter SDK and it went away with an update.

Alternatively, one could try switching to cocoapods for updates which was more efficient for me.